# How to check root or recovery installation datetime?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode

Is there anyway that I can find out the datetime of my smartphone being rooted,  or the TWRP recovery installation time?

Comment: Recovery, probably not, although you could look at the creation time of the TWRP directory... Same with the su binary, if it hasn't been updated the file modified time should give you what your looking for.

Comment: Alternatively, if your SU management app has logs, check those and find the earliest entry. One will likely test su access right after rooting the phone, so that entry should pretty accurately reflect the time.